# Will background sync on chrome take up extra mobile data?

Tags: samsung, chrome-for-android, mobile-data

I have the samsung a32 5g.

I noticed there's an option called background sync on chrome that supposedly makes sure interactions between others are done securely done without error. I know it probably uses more battery, but what about mobile data? Is it worth keeping it on if I'm mainly just going through the web, and will it affect data usage if I'm not sending emails?

Comment: Not sure if this description of [backrgound-sync](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync) refers to the same functionality but based on the description this seems to be a feature that can be used by web-sites to provide an offline-functionality for actions that sends data to a server. Data sending is just delayed and stored on device until you are online again.

Comment: I see, would it really matter for battery life or data?

Comment: For data it just a delay, if you send something now or in 10 minutes doesn't really care. For battery I don't know, the amount should not be really significant, as long as you don't use it with 100MB+ uploads.

Comment: Sorry to clarify you mean there will be a delay until there is a stable connection to send something if the sync is turned ON? I don't know how this would affect data but wouldn't it refresh some web pages or something while you're not using it and that's how extra data would be used?

Comment: What I wrote was only for the case where you are offline but perform an upload. If you are online ai don't know if data is sent directly. I would assume that depends on how the website is implemented.